# Swift 3 (SpriteKit) Adding a child to the GameScene from within a custom class

Tags: ios, swift, inheritance, sprite-kit

I am coding a Bullet Hell type game for the IOS, which features multiple enemies coming down toward the player. For the enemies, I created a custom class called Enemy which is a subclass of the SKSpritenode class.

```
class Enemy : SKSpriteNode {

    var type : String;
    var health : Int;
    var armor : Int;
    var healthBar : HealthBar; //The HealthBar Class

    init(type: String, position: CGPoint, texture : SKTexture, color: UIColor, size: CGSize){
        self.type = type;
        self.health = enemyHealths[self.type]!
        self.armor = enemyArmors[self.type]!
        self.healthBar = HealthBar(healthBarWidth: 40, healthBarHeight: 4, hostile: true, health: self.health, maxHealth: self.health, position: position) //Initialize HealthBar
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)

        self.position = position;
        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.size);
        self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false;
        self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0;
        self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true;

        self.addChild(self.healthBar) //Add HealthBar Instance

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func update(currentTime: TimeInterval){

    }
}
```

In this class I initialize another class, a HealthBar class, which is also a subclass of the SKSPritenode class, but when I try to add it as a child to the Enemy instance it shows up on the far right side of the screen. I am wondering if there are specific child position mechanics that are making this happen or of its just an error in the code. One thing I can think of might be causing this error is that when I update the HealthBar position I set its position to the same of the Enemy's, which is added as a child to the GameScene. This might cause an error with that coordinate not being available when the Healthbar is added as a child to the smaller Enemy.

[image: Swift Child Bug]

As you can see the Enemy spawns just fine, but the HealthBar is on the far right of the screen instead of being right above the Enemy where its supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out my suspicions were correct. Since you were adding a child to the smaller Enemy Instance, coordinate `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)` corresponded to the center of the Enemy Instance. Thus to get the HealthBar above the Enemy Instance, all you had to was set its position to the aforementioned coordinate with a small positive offset in the Y value.